# Use babel for transpiling vue template instead of buble

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, bublejs

I'm trying to use `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining` so I can do like `{{ user?.name || 'Oops' }}` in my vue templates. I have added the plugin to my babel.config.js, but it still comes up with a vue-loader error. After some searching it seems like vue uses buble instead of babel for transpiling the js inside the template tag.

Is there a way to use babel instead of buble for transpiling the js in the template?

Comment: It doesn't look like there's an option to configure `vue-template-compiler`, but since the Babel plugin works in the `<script>` block, a workaround would be to use a computed property that returns `user?.name`.

Comment: Yeah this is my fallback solution, too bad though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack, try this on build/webpack..conf.js 
(replace where the test matches and adjust to your preferences)

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            js: 'babel-loader'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [{
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: { presets: ['es2015'], compact: false }  // Add here your options!
        }]
      },
      ...
    ]
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

*Maybe you have to install and configure babel with a file .babelrc to add the proposal and babel-loader*

If not webpack, please, add more info about your project structure and the way to compile/transpile it (or migrate to webpack, is a good friend to transpile).

Also if you need more help let me know.

Hope it helps *at least a bit* :)

Comment: I used the Vue CLI to init the app, so the webpack config is auto generated. I tried your config (and added exclusion of node_modules), which results in "failed to mount template", but at least the dev server starts.

Using Vues inspect tool, I can see the webpack config, which is huge, and I have no idea whats going on. If you want to look: https://pastebin.com/Jm2nTYKZ

Its not THAT crucial for me to get that babel plugin to work, so maybe I should just give up.

Comment: And FYI, the plugins works fine when using it in .js or the <script> tag, its only the js in the template that doesn't go through babel